# Cannot find any good match for installing zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to learn zend framework so I was trying to understand the tutorials presented on their page.
Everything good until I wanted to install the framework. I followed the steps that send me to

```
https://framework.zend.com/download/latest
```

but when I enter here there was nothing, a 404 Not Found Error.

Then I try to install it manually and I also found on their site to use the command:

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework
```

but when I run in cmd it says that

```
'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

In conclusion I don't know what to do.Any suggestions how to resolve this and to install zend framework and work successfully?

Comment: can you show your vhost in apache2 configuration ?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md - go for 'global' rather than 'local' installation.

Comment: Seems like composer is not installed globally. Check out [composer global installation instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).

Answer (score 0):

It is required you say what SO you are using. If not we can explain you an improper solution.

I'll write a how to, which works properly on almost every Linux Debian flavors:

First open a console and log as superuser in order to install composer globally:

```
// type at your prompt (usually user@user-desktop:~$ )
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo -i
// you will be asked for password as follow
[sudo] password for user:
// Type it
```

Now you are logged as superuser and can install composer:

```
// (the prompt changes to some thing similar to root@user-desktop:~#) 
// Type the command:
root@user-desktop:~# apt-get install composer
```

Accept by Typing Y when system asks you, and take a cup of coffee while installer completes the job. 
Close the session by typing exit as follow:

```
root@user-desktop:~# exit
// Now you can install the last zendframework version (currently 3.0)
// the propmp returns to initial state. Type:
user@user-desktop:~$ composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

See the zendframework guide at [Zendframework Skeleton Application - Tutorials](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/) to read how to select the options you need.
Installer will ask you for them.

Hope it helps.